# Extract data from string and reframe it into another

Tags: apex, map, list, string, regular-expressions

I have got a string in below format:

`String test = '11, -22|32.45, 34|32, 41|32, 12.12';`

I am trying to convert it into below format:

`{"a":11,"b":-22|"a":32.45,"b":34|"a":32,"b":41| "a":32,"b":12.12}`

I tried using the logic by split() and then using join but couldn't achieve it and logic fails.

````
List<String> numVar = test.split('\\|');
String finalStr = '{';
for(String st : numVar){
finalStr += 'a:'+st.split(',')[0]+',';
finalStr += 'b:'+st.split(',')[1];
    //trying to add join by | logic here.
}
finalStr += '}';```
````

Comment: Why that format? Do you mean actual JSON? Or exactly as specified?

Comment: You should also [edit] your question to show us what you've tried so far. Even if it's wrong or runs into errors, it'll help people guide you through errors (conceptual, semantic, syntactic, etc...)

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes. the exact format. Basically a string is being converted into another JSON string.

Comment: Thanks @DerekF I have added the same in question.

Comment: Well... that's not JSON, but if that's what you're insisting on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use String.replaceAll to match patterns

```
String testString = '11, -22|32.45, 34|32, 41|32, 12.12';
String resultString = '{'+testString.replaceAll('(-?[\\d+\\.]+), ?(-?[\\d+\\.]+)','"a":$1,"b":$2')+'}';
System.debug(resultString); // {"a":11,"b":-22|"a":32.45,"b":34|"a":32,"b":41|"a":32,"b":12.12}
```

This avoids the need to split and/or use any loops at all.

---

Edit:

For the regular expression, we have the following concepts:

- In Apex, a literal `\` must be escaped, because Apex uses this as an escape character, too.
- To match a literal `\` in Regex, we need to escape it: `\\` (not used here).
- So, to match a literal `\` in Regex/Apex, we need to write `\\\\` (not used here).
- `[...]` specifies a character set, for which we use `[0123456789\.]+`, which is also simply `[\d\.]`.
- `?` means "match zero or once".
- `+` means "match at least once".
- `(...)` is a "capture group", which we can later reference as `$1`, `$2`, etc for each group from left to right.

For a more complete regular expression tutorial, consider a site like regex101.com, regular-expressions.info, etc.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox 
That helped. I would highly appreciate some regex lessons I can take up as a beginner.

I knew this can be fixed by regex but gave up as I couldn't frame the regex.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user15754268 Added a crash course. You should definitely check out additional resources, there's a lot out there.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the first split on the pipe (`|`) is going to give you a list of strings like
`['11, -22', '32.45, 34', '32, 41', '32, 12.12']`

So to process this further, you'll either need to `split()` again, or just use `replace()` with a simple regex.

ex.

```
// Doesn't hurt to do this outside of the loop, but it also doesn't help
//List<String> parts = testStr.split('\\|');

List<String> processed = new List<String>();
for(String part :testStr.split('\\|')){
    system.debug(part); // should print things like '32.45, 34'

    // Using some simple regex with capturing groups to get the a/b part of the format
    // The $1 and $2 get replaced with the first and second capturing groups
    //   (the stuff contained inside the `()`) respectively
    // [0-9.-]+ covers integer strings, decimal strings, and negative numbers
    processed.add(part.replace('([0-9\\-.]+), ([0-9\\-.]+)', '"a":$1,"b":$2));
}
```

The result of that should be `['"a":11,"b":-22', "a":32.45,"b":34', '"a":32,"b":41','"a":32,"b":12.12']`. The square braces just indicate that it's part of a list.

From there, it should be a simple `String.join()` to get the final output

Comment: Or, you know, String.replaceAll.